# Query to select the sum of count in master table depend on details table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have database has tables something like this
[image: database relation]

I can not change the database structure

I want to write query to bring the sum of the count of all mobiles which have (a camera and its color is red) for example

I found a way but it is so complicated

can you help me if there is a sample way please?

Comment: It's a matter of simple JOIN, should not be complicated, please show your SQL code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(mobile_count) Total
FROM [master] M
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [details]
             WHERE master_fk = M.master_id
             AND mobile_camera = 1
             AND mobile_color = 'red')
```

On an unrelated note, I really hope that you chose an unclustered index for your primary key, since you are using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Comment: sorry for being late, but I did not understand what do you main by `chose an unclestered index`

Comment: @Aroo there are many links explaining why using `NEWID()` to generate GUIDs used as a clustered index is a bad idea: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/glennberry/2010/03/22/why-uniqueidentifier-is-a-bad-choice-for-a-clustered-index-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(mobile_count) Total
FROM [master] M join [Details] D ON M.master_id = D.master_fk
WHERE mobile_camera = 1 AND mobile_color = 'red'
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this yields needed result?

```
SELECT SUM(mobile_count)
FROM master INNER JOIN details ON master_id = master_fk
WHERE mobile_camera = 1 and mobile_color = 'red'
```